# Translate Zend Framework website like WPML in Wordpress

Tags: zend-framework, wordpress, po

I want to know if it's possible to translate a Zend Framework 1 website in a manner similar with the one implemented by [WPML](http://wpml.org/) for [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

What I want is to make an application that can scan the website source code for translation variables, then store them in a database or a *[.po](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html)* file.

Also please note that I am not interested in switching to another framework or using only Wordpress for my website but in a method of simple and easy translation for someone without programming skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

- **Zend_Translate** with **gettext adapter**
- **Zend_Registry**
- **Poedit**

More info [here](http://www.tornstrand.com/2008/03/29/string-localization-with-gettext-and-zend-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

PoEdit http://www.poedit.net/download.php

I have used this software to create .mo files for Zend_Translate gettext adapter in one of my ZF projects.